# Где хранить данные string или БД?

Tags: android, строки, sqlite

Есть 30 кнопок. По нажатию на "кнопку 1" - вынимается "текст 1", по нажатию на "кнопку 4" вынимается "текст 4" (каждый текст содержит чуть больше 1000 слов). Функциональность приложения состоит только в вынимании текста при нажатии на кнопку бокового меню.

Так вот, в чем минусы, если хранить эти тексты не в БД, а в `string`? Или для такого приложения можно хранить и в `string`, и будет лишь несущественное увеличение веса `apk-файла`? Не спрашивайте пожалуйста "в чем проблема сделать БД?". Мне интересно лишь минусы использования `string` для хранения данных. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При таких исходных данных принципиального различия где хранить текст нету. Реализовывайте как вам удобнее можно через БД можно через string. Обратите внимание на возможное развитие Вашего приложения (добавление других языков,функционала) и исходя из этого принимайте решение.

Comment: меняться будет только количество текста (кнопок). 2 фрагмента (один только текст), второй (текст и 2 кнопки, которые также переключают текст).. и двухуровневое меню. С этим всем подойдет использование данных в string, не будет "есть" память и создавать дискомфорт пользователю?

Comment: все очень просто, подойдет и string. если бы в дальнейших планах было редактирование этого текста, добавление информации в существующий текст и т.п., то тогда лучше было бы БД использовать. По скорости и памяти на таких объемах разницу пользователь не почувствует

Comment: я бы выбрал хранение данных в сети.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду динамическое редактирование текста? Поскольку в обновлениях я иногда буду добавлять в тексте пару строк, но это не в приложении, а программно, как сейчас я его создаю. 

К сожалению, принципиальная задача сделать приложение, которое можно использовать без доступа к интернету.

Comment: да, я говорил о динамическом редактировании текста пользователем. если вы в обновлении будете что то менять в тексте , то все остаеется в рамках ранее данного ответа